# TabBar overlay on view - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode10.2

I shift my `TabBar` to top like bellow:

```
class RootMainFatherTabBarUITabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        //Shift tabs to top page
        tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    }
}
```

But `TabBar` overlay on view and i can't see `segue`!

Comment: A `UITabBarController` is not designed to be at the top of the screen and you are going to be fighting all kinds of issues if you try to make it.  I would suggest re-thinking your interface instead.

Comment: @ Upholder Of Truth. What can I do?

Comment: In what way?  You can design a different style interface isn't based on a `UITabBarController`.  Perhaps make your own custom version if you really want it to be like that.

Comment: I can use from other way but what way?

Comment: That's going to depend on what you want it to look like.  You could use some kind of menu instead or make a custom button bar that switches the view controllers.  There are many different options I was just trying to avoid you wasting time trying to bend the `UITabBarController` to do what it's not designed to do.

Comment: I just need to pass tab bar to top and set view under the tab bar. :(

Comment: Ok if you mean it's overlaying the status bar then you can do something like this: `        self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height), size: self.tabBar.frame.size)
`.  I would also put it after the call to super so that is all complete.  The point I am trying to make though is that it would be better not to do that at all as it will break the Apple HIGs.

Answer (score 0):

you can add tabbar by easy and fast way just open ui-control-view and drag and drop tabbar 
ADD tab and just click and swipe and drop on the nav view thats you want to open